# Tail -f is not showing the update of the file when edited form editor

Tags: tail, echo

I have opened a file using `tail -f <filename`, and tried to append some texts in the same file from another tab using **vim**, the updated content is not showing. But if I append some texts using `echo` it works fine. Is there anything specific that I don't know?

**tail** man page says:

> -f, --follow[={name|descriptor}]
> output appended data as the file grows;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim (or any text editor) keeps two files when editing, the edited file and
the new file. The new file only has a temporary name.
When Vim updates the file, it actually just renames the new file and deletes
the old file.

The `man` page says:

> With --follow (-f), tail defaults to following the file
> descriptor, which means that even if a tail'ed file is renamed,
> tail will continue to track its end.  This default behavior is
> not desirable when you really want to track the actual name of
> the file, not the file descriptor (e.g., log rotation).  Use
> --follow=name in that case.  That causes tail to track the named
> file in a way that accommodates renaming, removal and creation.

You need to specify `name` for the file with that name to be followed,
regardless of its file descriptor
(which is only valid as long as the file is still open).

Use the command as:

```
tail --follow=name filename
```

Comment: Thanks but what about `echo`ing?

Comment: I don't understand the remark.

Comment: Why does following the descriptor work when I append to the file by the `echo` command?

Comment: Because the file is still open, so its file-descriptor is still valid. Every open file has a file-descriptor which is just a number. When the file is closed, it becomes invalid. Vim closes the file and the new file has the same name, but a different file-descriptor. That's why `tail` loses it. With "--follow=name" it will track the file by its name, not by the file-descriptor.

Comment: //Because the file is still open, so its file-descriptor is still valid// Who opened it? Will it remain  open ?

Comment: Tail opened it when invoked and keeps it open. Vim deleted it and replaced it by another file of the same name. With "--follow=name", tail will keep opening it as many times as required when it's replaced by vim.

Comment: Thanks. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

In Unix, files are opened by name but referenced by inode.  If you `tail -f X` and then open `X` in Emacs (for example), after you make your changes and save the file, Emacs will rename the original file to `X~` and write out a new file named `X`.  Your `tail -f X` inode is now pointing at `X~` while `X` has a new inode.  Vim may work the same, or it may simply delete the original `X` file and create a new one.  (Unix won't remove a file until all inode references to it are gone so, assuming no other hard links to `X`, your `tail -f` is keeping the old `X` file "alive.")

When you run `echo foo >> X`, the echo command opens `X` for append; thus, the inode will not change after the file is appeneded to and closed.

You can easily see the inodes of files using the `-i` switch in `ls`.